# How to run SQL that has declare statements via SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

This is a sample query:

```sql
declare @tempTable table 
(
    Id bigint
)

-- populating with temp Ids

select *
from TargetTable
where Id not in 
(
    select Id 
    from @tempTable
)
```

And this is C# code:

```cs
public DataTable Get(string sql)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        dataTable.Load(dataReader);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Running this code throws exception, complaining that:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.
>   Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

I know it's possible to use join instead of `@tempTable`, but is there a way to run this query?

Comment: The part of the query you've posted here is valid. It is possible that the errors comes from the parts you've replaced with `-- populating with temp Ids`. Please [edit] your question to include the exact SQL you are sending to the database.

Comment: How are you putting the code into the `sql` variable. (I have used – via Dapper which uses `SqlCommand` – commands including `declare` statements in the past so I suspect some issue with the text being sent.

Comment: What if you wrap that in a stored procedure and rather run that from your application

Comment: why not just simply code the query as `where Id not in ( id1, id2, id3 .. .) ` ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I have a long Query and when I run it inside SSMS, it works just fine.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thanks for your note. From your comment I realized that I had a syntactic problem in creating the query. I was trying to solve the issue of creating temp tables inside ADO.NET queries.

Comment: Then try to simplify it to the minimal example that reproduce the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

A `SqlDataAdapter` object can be used to populate a `DataTable` as follows.  Instead of calling `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` method is used.  In this example the argument to the `Fill()` method is the `DataTable` that will be populated.  While this approach will work with the query you posted with the table variable, I'd strongly recommend converting this to a stored procedure and filling the `DataTable` from this instead.  Additionally, unless the amount of data that's being sent into the table variable is very small using a temp table will offer more functionality (more accurate statistics, better DML performance, `ROLLBACK` participation, etc.)  than table variables and I'd suggest using a temp table instead as well.

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);

            da.SelectCommand = command;
            connection.Open();
            da.Fill(dataTable);
        }
```

**Stored Procedure Call:**

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

            //use SP name for command text
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_ProcedureName", connection);

            //stored procedure command type
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand = command;
            connection.Open();
            da.Fill(dataTable);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Procedure of your query then add this to your code:

```
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Then use `exec` command

```
command.CommandText = "exec procedureName"
```

If your query location is in database itself.

Comment: You don't need `exec` if the `CommandType` is `StoredProcedure`.

Comment: Oh i see.. it must be `commandType.Text`. Your right @Zohar Peled